# Function EXTRACT does not support NUMBER(38,0) argument type in SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am in the process of converting Custom SQL to Snowflake for use in a Tableau extract. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error message after converting the code:

> Function EXTRACT does not support NUMBER(38,0) argument type

It is UNION All Snowflake piece of code and I'm trying to get the correct answer. Any ideas!

Comment: you need to provide sample data and also your code

Comment: what's the goal of using `EXTRACT` here?

Answer (score 1):

One of your columns is NUMBER(38, 0) and it needs to be converted to `date`, `time`, or `timestamp` first. Here is some example

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    TO_DATE(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_OF_BIRTH))
FROM
    PERSON;
```

Answer (score 0):

from error message , `extract` function in snowflake only gets `date`, `time`, or `timestamp` as input argument and clearly you are passing an argument with `NUMBER(38,0)` data type

see : [EXTRACT- snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/extract.html) for more info.